# find a replace multiple strings in a matching code block using sed

Tags: linux, sed, replace, find

Please any help on this using Linux "sed" will be appreciated. 
I have the code block as below in a file. Looking to extract a block starting with "aa.bb.cc.config=" and end with "}". From the extracted block, find the strings ["bb11:11211"]  ["ff5rt:11211"] and delete the matching lines from the file.

```
asdf={
ddd, \
fff, \
ggg \
}
ghjk
wwww
aa.bb.cc.config={"List": [ \
"aa11:222", \
"bb11:11211", \
"cc22ss:11211", \
"dd33ss:11211", \
"ff5rt:11211", \
"gg6hj:11211", \
], "dd": true, "ff": 0, "hh": 0, "jj": 10, "kk": 0 }

vsdfsdf
ewqewqe
```

OUTPUT:

```
asdf={
ddd, \
fff, \
ggg \
}
ghjk
wwww
aa.bb.cc.config={"List": [ \
"aa11:222", \
"cc22ss:11211", \
"dd33ss:11211", \
"gg6hj:11211", \
], "dd": true, "ff": 0, "hh": 0, "jj": 10, "kk": 0 }

vsdfsdf
ewqewqe
```

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: you know about sed, why not give it a try to solve it by yourself? if you got stuck, then add the code you tried to question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***sed*** approach:

```
sed '/^aa\.bb\.cc\.config=/,/}$/{ /\"\(bb11\|ff5rt\):11211\"/d; }' file
```

- `/^aa.bb.cc.config=/,/}$/` - address range, considering lines from `/^aa.bb.cc.config=/` to `/}$/`
- `/\"\(bb11\|ff5rt\):11211\"/d;` - delete lines matched the pattern within captured pattern space

---

The same using extended regex `-E`:

```
sed -E '/^aa\.bb\.cc\.config=/,/\}$/{ /"(bb11|ff5rt):11211"/d; }' file
```

---

The output:

```
asdf={
ddd, \
fff, \
ggg \
}
ghjk
wwww
aa.bb.cc.config={"List": [ \
"aa11:222", \
"cc22ss:11211", \
"dd33ss:11211", \
"gg6hj:11211", \
], "dd": true, "ff": 0, "hh": 0, "jj": 10, "kk": 0 }

vsdfsdf
ewqewqe
```

Comment: Thanks actually its working on GNU based. I need this on BSD based OS.

Comment: Try `sed -E` to allow alternation with the vertical bar.

Comment: @raffiqu, use my second approach